# Saving list to a sharedPref. using GSON Nullpointer error

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, sharedpreferences

I have the following code:

```
public class CustomGesture extends Activity {

private static Spinner spinner1, spinner2;
private static Button btn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.custom_gesture);
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    // list.add("peepu");
    // list.add("Cheecki");
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("cheeku");
    list.add("matthu");
    SharedPreferences appSharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getApplicationContext());
    Editor prefsEditor = appSharedPrefs.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(list);
    prefsEditor.putString("MyObject", json);
    prefsEditor.commit();
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    dataAdapter
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                     SharedPreferences appSharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
                              .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                              Gson gson = new Gson();
                              String json = appSharedPrefs.getString("MyObject", "");
                              List<String> list = gson.fromJson(json, null);
                    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
                    dataAdapter
                            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    spinner2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
                }
            }).start();
        }
    });
}
```

}

the error I'm getting is the following :

```
04-13 13:50:20.066: E/AndroidRuntime(2358): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-5592
04-13 13:50:20.066: E/AndroidRuntime(2358): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-13 13:50:20.066: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Preconditions.checkNotNull($Gson$Preconditions.java:35)
04-13 13:50:20.066: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken.<init>(TypeToken.java:72)
04-13 13:50:20.066: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken.get(TypeToken.java:296)
04-13 13:50:20.066: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:801)
04-13 13:50:20.066: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768)
04-13 13:50:20.066: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:717)
04-13 13:50:20.066: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:689)
04-13 13:50:20.066: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at com.winacro.Bsquares.CustomGesture$1$1.run(CustomGesture.java:60)
04-13 13:50:20.066: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

I think this error is because Im using null as a parameter in the fromJSON ,but what to use instead of the null parameter I think I cannot use a list there?

Comment: ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);

Comment: OKay I solved it I need to make the Array that I'm feeding to the spinner compatible with the list type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharedPrefrences is used to store small amount of data, such as flags and static strings, you went for a workaround to store a json-formatted string it works for a very small json object otherwise you need to use sqlite, [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/) is a tutoial

Comment: I'm trying to add the Data as >> db.addDATA(new Data("Srinivas", "9199999999"));   but I'm getting it saved as04-13 17:48:33.246: D/CHECKKK********(22741): com.example.cheeki.Data@429af408 when I retrieve it!